# Want to plot a decision tree in R got this error: (sapply(split, tail, 1) %in% mf_levels[[var_id]]) is not TRUE

Tags: r, plot, decision-tree

I use J48 to generate a decision tree below, when I want to plot it by using

```
if(require("party",quietly=TRUE)) plot(fit_1)
```

it gives an error:

> Error: all(sapply(split, tail, 1) %in% mf_levels[[var_id]]) is not TRUE

what does this error mean?

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled upon the same issue and reached out to the CRAN community for help. The issue relies primarily on the encoding of your datafile which is using non-ASCII labels without properly declaring them when importing the file.

Achim Zeileis (admin of the partykit library) provided the following answer -->

> To avoid the problem you can either:
>
> - avoid non-ASCII labels which is usually the most robust solution where you have to pay less attention what exactly you are doing.
> - Or you properly declare the encoding of your data file as follows:

```
dataframe <- read.csv("mynonASCII_data.csv", header=T,sep=',',
**encoding = "proper_encoding"**)

#proper encoding could be any non-ASCII encoding such as 'latin1' for example

resultJ48 <- J48(class~., dataframe, control = Weka_control(M = 2, C =0.5))

x <- as.party(resultJ48)
```

as.party should work now for your plot